# TSQL: How to optimize this update query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, sql-server-2000

I have been working to optimize a procedure created by another programmer at my work by re-writting the entire query to use block statements rather than cursors. I have run into a problem however. I let my procedure run for an hour and it never finished (whereas the cursor procedure finished in 30 minutes). I started debugging and found it never getting past the following query:

```
    -- Create our temp table
    create table #tData(
        First varchar(50) null,
        Middle varchar(50) null,
        Last varchar(50) null,
        Address varchar(50) null,
        Address2 varchar(50) null,
        City varchar(30) null,
        State varchar(2) null,
        Zip varchar(20) null,
        Phone varchar(20) null,
        SSN varchar(20) null,
        DOB varchar(15) null,
        Gender varchar(1) null,
        cID int null,
        pNum varchar(50) null,
        POFlag bit null,
        MatchFound bit null,
        Status varchar(10) null
    )

    -- Index the temp table
    create clustered index IX_tData_Clust on #tData(First, Middle, Last, Address, SSN, DOB)
    create index IX_tData on #tData(First, Middle, Last, Address, SSN, DOB)

    -- Look for matches
    update 
        #tData 
    set 
        #tData.MatchFound = 1,
        #tData.cID = ClientDatabase.cID,
        #tData.pNum = ClientDatabase.pNum
    from
        #tData,
        ClientDatabase
    where
        #tData.Status = 'ACTIVE'
        and (
                (
                    #tData.SSN is not null
                    and ClientDatabase.SSN is not null
                    and #tData.SSN = ClientDatabase.SSN
                ) 
                or 
                (
                    #tData.First is not null
                    and ClientDatabase.FirstName is not null
                    and #tData.Last is not null
                    and ClientDatabase.LastName is not null
                    and #tData.Address is not null
                    and ClientDatabase.AddressLine1 is not null
                    and #tData.First = ClientDatabase.FirstName
                    and #tData.Last = ClientDatabase.LastName
                    and #tData.Address = ClientDatabase.AddressLine1
                )
            )
```

Basically the above query has a temp table (#tData) of data that was bulk inserted from a text file. It is then trying to find matches in the ClientDatabase (which has over 5 million entries). Once it has found a match, it updates the MatchFound, cID, and pNum cells of the table row. I have tested it with small insert files (5 rows) and it seems to complete just fine. When I get into the thousands, like most of our files will be, it just poops out.

I did some further research and debugging and found the machine it is currently running on is being maxed on all 6 cores and it appears to be just hanging after that point until the procedure is forced to quit.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I might be able to optimize the above query or perhaps how to make it so SQL can better manage the query? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It's a bit too broad question and one needs a lot more details about your schema/data. Best we can do to help you is to point a course of action and give some tips. First one is you must study the actual query plan for this thing to start to find bottlenecks

Comment: why are you updating #temp table?

Comment: @hmd Trying to keep the data all in one place for consistency reasons? Would it really make a difference inserting into another table where a match was found?

Comment: @jean Im running the query again right now with the execution plan being shown, I will see if I can identify any bottlenecks. My previous debugging led me to this point anyways. This is the point where CPU spikes on the main machine and it hangs. In my actual procedure I have many debug messages being printed out everywhere - right before that query is the last message I get.

Comment: Do not do it just for consistency reason. Looks like you have a big query, your aim should be optimize it. Clear code is always better though. 1Hour query time is not acceptable. If cursor is faster than your query, you have a huge problem there. Cursors are terribly slow.

Comment: @hmd I know cursours are terrible. That was the point of this little project. Ill see about inserting into a new table.

Comment: Your redundant duplicate indexes may not be helping very much. For example, checking `Status` gets no benefit. Checking `SSN` to match against the other table is extremely unlikely to benefit. Try an index on the fields in an order in which they are useful: `Status`, `SSN`, and then the name and address data. You may want to check the indexes on `ClientDatabase` and contemplate the order of fields you find there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the first part in your `WHERE` clause reads:

```
where
    #tData.Status = 'ACTIVE'
    -- ...
```

You need to put an `INDEX` on the `Status` field.

---

Second, I would break the `UPDATE` statement in two statements, one for each `OR`-part. Also remove the `NULL` checks because when you finally compare the fields, the fields cannot be null for the condition to be true (unless you have [`ANSI_NULLS`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259229%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) set to `OFF`, but I doubt that):

```
update 
-- snipped for brevity 
where
    #tData.Status = 'ACTIVE'
    and #tData.SSN = ClientDatabase.SSN
```

Plus

```
update 
-- snipped for brevity 
where
    #tData.Status = 'ACTIVE'
    and #tData.First = ClientDatabase.FirstName
    and #tData.Last = ClientDatabase.LastName
    and #tData.Address = ClientDatabase.AddressLine1
```

---

Third, now that things have cleared up, you will see that these `UPDATE` statements are easier to read using new-school JOIN statements (read [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)).

```
update 
    #tData 
set 
    #tData.MatchFound = 1,
    #tData.cID = ClientDatabase.cID,
    #tData.pNum = ClientDatabase.pNum
from
    #tData
    INNER JOIN ClientDatabase ON
        #tData.SSN = ClientDatabase.SSN
where
    #tData.Status = 'ACTIVE'
```

Plus

```
update 
    #tData 
set 
    #tData.MatchFound = 1,
    #tData.cID = ClientDatabase.cID,
    #tData.pNum = ClientDatabase.pNum
from
    #tData
    INNER JOIN ClientDatabase ON
        #tData.First = ClientDatabase.FirstName
        and #tData.Last = ClientDatabase.LastName
        and #tData.Address = ClientDatabase.AddressLine1
where
    #tData.Status = 'ACTIVE'
```

---

Fourth: Since the lookup for the match is in table `ClientDatabase` I think you need indices in `ClientDatabase`. One for `SSN` lookup, one for the `FirstName + LastName + AddressLine1` lookup.

Inspecting the [Actual Execution Plan](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa178423%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) will most likely reveal that. If such indices do no exist it will likely result in several table scans which will wreck performance.

```
create nonclustered index IX_ClientDatabase_SSN on ClientDatabase(SSN);
create nonclustered index IX_ClientDatabase_Name_Address on ClientDatabase(FirstName,LastName,AddressLine1);
```

Comment: This answer was beautiful. Applied the suggested changes and the query finishes in 12 minutes. Thank you very much

Comment: @Vince You're welcome of course =). I would argue that 12 minutes is still too much, so there's probably room for more improvement. Inspecting the execution plan might reveal more insight into what can be optimized.

Comment: I took your advice and looked for bottlenecks in the execution plan. I was able to reduce 12 minutes to 9 minutes. There is one more big time eater (84% of the execution cost) but I cant seem to figure out what is going on with it. Any idea?

`insert into ClientSaveDatabase
     select * from ClientDatabase where ClientDatabase.ClientName = @ClientName`

There is a nonclustered index on the client name for the clientdatabase.

Comment: @Vince One more idea I had: include the `MatchFound` in the `INDEX` I proposed in the first point (second field, so `Status, MatchFound`). Then in the second update statement, add `AND #tData.MatchFound`. This will only look up matches for rows that weren't already matched in the first `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: @Vince About the statement in your comments, it appears you would also need an `INDEX` on `ClientDatabase` with the field `ClientName`. Another thing, if you're running these statements in a stored procedure, you might be facing a Parameter Sniffing issue. If that's the case, first copy the stored procedure parameter `@ClientName` in a local variable, and use the local variable in the query. So `DECLARE @ClientNameLocal VARCHAR(128); SET @ClientNameLocal=@ClientName;`. Query: `insert into ClientSaveDatabase select * from ClientDatabase where ClientDatabase.ClientName = @ClientNameLocal`.

Comment: Adding to the status index appeared to slow down the procedure a bit, not entirely sure why. In addition, I did the change you suggested and it dropped the execution cost to 78% so there was some increase on that insert statement.

Comment: @Vince Did you add `AND #tData.MatchFound=0` to the second update statement in conjuction with the index including `MatchFound`? Anyway it's quite possible if the number of matches in the first update statement is low, than it won't matter all that much (or slow down even as your experience).

Answer (score 0):

I dont exactly know why are you updating a temp (#temporary) table but I will give some suggestions.

Updating #temp table is probably a bad idea in your case because you have millions of records to match against and #temp table wont have indexes.

A better approach would be create a table which has indices on it, then insert data into it, then match it against index column in your main table, that way your query will be dramatically faster. So something like this

CREATE #TABLE(colum1 as primary key, columne2,.... columnn)
INSERT INTO #TABLE() VALUES()

Now your temp table will be just as fast and your query should be really fast as well. Note the above code is pseudo.

Comment: I actually do have indexes (First, Last, Address, SSN, DOB) on the temporary table. They are assigned right after the creation of the temp table. I imagine it really wouldn't make a difference though. Im editing the main post to show the creation of the temp table.